# FacesTrace JSF project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2

I try to configure FacesTrace in my Project (web dynamic project) in Eclipse and JSF 2.0.
I downloaded facetrace-1.0.1.jar and coppy it in web-inif/lib folder. And on my page index.xhtml I defined:

xmlns:ft="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/facestrace"

an ad on the end of page I written

Bath I can not deployed project. Does anyone know something about it

supplement of the question:

deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: jar:file:/C:/GlassFish4/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/MojAutoComplete/WEB-INF/lib/facestrace-1.1.0.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'org.primefaces.facestrace.phase.listener.TraceResourcePhaseListener' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;. Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you get an error?

Comment: yes I added in my question, upper!

Comment: As the exception says you're missing `org/apache/commons/logging/Log` class, which is required by facestrace, in your classpath. Get the [apache commons loging jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3), which seems to be the required dependecy and add it to your deploy package.

Comment: End I can add it in web-inf/lib Folder?

Comment: Yeaaah super it works!!! Thanks a lot!!!